# TinyMCE Toolbar on mobile

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm having an issue where the toolbar on mobile devices is so small.  On both my android and iPhone:

[image]

On my phone, those buttons are hard to press and if I pull the page down it refreshes.  Here is the code I use to initialize the editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    height: 350,
    menubar: "edit format",
    plugins: "lists",
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    mobile: {
        theme: "mobile",
        plugins: "lists",
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
    }
});
```

and I'm using a textarea

```
<textarea id="tiny-editor"></textarea>
```

I've searched online and don't really see what I'm doing differently.  Any advice would be appreciated.

**Update 1**
OK so it's my fault since I set the font size to font-size: 62.5%; on the head and looking into the editor style I see its sets the height using em in the file skin.mobile.min.css has the height 2.5em

Comment: It's weird that only some of the icons shrank. You might be able to use CSS to apply a `font-size: initial !important` override on the mobile theme outer container to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using TinyMCE before and although it's good on desktop views, I was never able to make it work well while using it on a mobile view. Because of this, we switched to Summernote. https://summernote.org/
This is a bit simpler than TinyMCE but is much easier to use and get to work on mobile. It's also free and doesn't have a paid version which is always nice.

Comment: The mobile theme had a good foundation but we never iterated on it. We are working to update the new desktop theme in v5 to be mobile-responsive and hope to use it as the primary mobile theme in v5.1.